# Why SoapUI execution via command line is printing directory files

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, soapui

I am trying to execute a SoapUI **5.2.1** test via command line with a command like this:

```
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat -s
"TestSuite 1" -c "Test001" -M -j -f "c:\auto" -r "C:\soapui-project.xml"
```

Apparently, this works fine.
The problem is that the execution always prints a list of all files existing in the directory from where I am running the test.

**Example:**

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is ABC1-2BAC

 Directory of C:\Users\abc\Desktop

08/06/2017  13:55    <DIR>          .
08/06/2017  13:55    <DIR>          ..
21/04/2017  11:57    <DIR>          folder1
26/05/2017  13:00    <DIR>          file2
07/10/2016  17:24    <DIR>          fileN
more files and folders ...
```

How can I avoid that? If I execute it from `"Temp"` folder, a 10 seconds test takes about 10 minutes to execute because is listing tons and tons of files.

Thank you.

Comment: Using for so long, never experienced like that. Check if there are any changes in bat file or any groovy script has that printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of runs and debugs I finally figured it out.
Here's the tip:

I just removed command "**dir**" from the end of "**C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat**" file and this solves my problem. Simple as that.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: It is not part of bat file provided by out-of-the-box, changes were made to bat file which unexpected by any one.

Comment: Hi, this is not a bat file provided out-of-the-box. This is the default installation of soapui 5.2.1.